# no sound internal speakers but ok on headphone

Tags: sound, alsa

I installed LUBUNTU20.04 on my Lenovo3000 Y410 laptop. I installed all required drivers, now everything is working fine but no sound from internal speakers. Headphone is working fine. I check alsamixer, speakers sound null there then I set it to 100 but got no sound . On reboot again speakers sound setting becomes null.
[alsamixer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKxtF.)

[alsa setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwRF9.png)
[pulseaudio setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwRF9.png)
[volume control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy12V.png)

Thaks.
Please help.

Comment: Have you got your audio configure through ALSA or PULSE?  (refer https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html or look for Volume Control Settings screenshot). You've not given us much info on your chosen setup, nor why you switched from Pulse Audio to Alsa.

Comment: Thanks dear guiverc,

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the solution of my sound related problem. I uninstalled pulseaudio completely and then did alsamixer settings for speakers and other parameters. Now everything working fine. I found that alsa and pulseaudio are conflicting at some point so I uninstalled them one by one. First I uninstalled alsa but problem remained as it is, then I uninstalled pulseaudio and installed alsa only. After setting sound parameters it worked well.
Thanks all.